# How to refer a temporary table inside EXTERNAL_QUERY() function of the GCP BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-spanner

[ERROR IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89PA1.png)
I'm working with EXTERNAL_QUERY function of the GCP BigQuery. The idea is to retrieve data from two separate GCP Spanner databases and process this data in one big SQL query. EXTERNAL_QUERY function provides this external data to the main query (EXTERNAL_QUERY("<db_path>", "<SQL query>")).
The main query execution starts from selection data to a temporary table, and after that referring this temporary table in the second parameter of the EXTERNAL_QUERY. But this approach is not working, because SQL query that I provide to EXTERNAL_QUERY as a string cannot use any temporary table. So is it possible to refer a temporary table in the EXTERNAL_QUERY function?

I haven't found anything about this issue in the GCP docks. Off course I can retrieve all rows from the external table and process this data, but this approach is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this all in BigQuery?

```sql
WITH transactions as (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection_string",
   "SELECT user_id, id FROM transactions")
),
das as (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("connection_string",
  "SELECT user_id FROM destination_accounts WHERE status = 'PENDING'"
  )
)
SELECT
  user_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT transactions.id)
FROM
  das
JOIN 
  transactions
USING 
  (user_id)
GROUP BY 
  user_id;
```

Your external transaction query is executed on GCP Spanner, so it doesn't know anything about `das`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Peter! Your query is valid, and it's working fine. But it doesn't resolve my problem. In your case, the query retrieves all data from chosen columns of the external table, and it can be huge. This separate DB is used by a lot of different microservices for storing user data, and my app uses only a bit of it. So this approach is not efficient, and also is more expensive.
I think about storing `das` data in some kind of variable, and then putting it into the EXTERNAL_QUERY function

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, there is no way to link tables from different databases. All we can do is manipulate strings.

So here is my solution.

- Select data from one remote database into a temporary table.
- Create a string with a list of keys from this table.
- Interpolate it into IN() clause for a query that is going to be send to the second remote DB.

Like this:

```
BEGIN 

DECLARE USER_IDS STRING;
DECLARE SELECT_TRANSACTIONS_QUERY STRING;

CREATE TEMP TABLE users AS
    SELECT userId FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY(
      "projects/<project>/locations/<location>/connections/<connection>",
      "SELECT userId FROM users;"
    );

SET USER_IDS = CONCAT("'", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT userId FROM users), "', '"), "'");

SET SELECT_TRANSACTIONS_QUERY = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE userId IN(', USER_IDS, ')');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
"""
  SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("projects/<project>/locations/<location>/connections/<connection>", ?);
"""
USING SELECT_TRANSACTIONS_QUERY;

END;
```

All this can be saved as a procedure and triggered by name from the backend.